# How to track a website/ server/ webservice/ winservice performance using C#?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0

How to track a website/ server/ webservice/ winservice performance i.e. up time, down time, which service is running and which is not running and if not running what is the error, Traffic-Jam status of message-queues, I have to show all these information in a grid view. How this can be achieved using C#, .Net? My current project needs this. Please share any code-snippet or link, that will be very helpful to me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a very broad question. What have you tred so far? Where did you encounter problems? Try breaking it down and ask more concrete questions.

Comment: Hi! EluciusFTW. My client has several web applications, windows applications, web services and window services and the client wants me to  build another application, that will track or monitor these applications and show the details such as which server is running or not running, whether any error encountered or not? I am not getting how to do this?